# Running Metal System Trace instrument

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, metal

I've built a simple application using Metal and it runs perfectly fine on my iPhone 5s. Now I'm trying to use Metal System Trace instrument, but apparently it's giving me this error message.

```
Version 1 or greater for com.apple.instruments.server.services.deviceinfo.metal required. Found version -1.
```

I'm I missing any steps or is there any extra configuration that I need to set before I can run the instrument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Metal System Trace* instrument requires iOS 9. That error appears if you attempt to run the *Metal System Trace* instrument for a device running iOS 8.

Comment: Yeah. Figured it out too. The error message is not really helping. Anyway, thanks